# DNS Server with netty, dig is right but browser can not connect to web

Tags: dns, netty

I try to write a simple DNS server with netty. When I use the dig command it returns the right result, but when I change my DNS server to my server and use a browser to visit the domain it fails. I think the browser does not get an IP address from DNS server.

My IP is `192.168.43.245`. I opened a web server on port 80, and tried to visit `aaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa` (a test domain that returns `192.168.43.245`) with my browser but it cannot connect.

```
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramDnsQuery query){
        ByteBuf answerIP;
        int logID;
        DatagramDnsResponse response = new DatagramDnsResponse(query.recipient(), query.sender(), query.id());
        DefaultDnsQuestion dnsQuestion = query.recordAt(DnsSection.QUESTION);
        String connectIP = query.sender().getHostName();
        String domainRegex = "\\.\\d+\\."+domain.replace(".","\\.")+"\\.$";
        String subDomain = dnsQuestion.name().replaceAll(domainRegex,"");
        String[] hd = dnsQuestion.name().replace('.'+domain+'.',"").split("\\.");
        try{
            logID = Integer.parseInt(hd[hd.length-1]);
        }catch (NumberFormatException n){
            return;
        }
        String ipRegex = "^((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d))|[0-1]?\\d{1,2})(\\.((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d))|[0-1]?\\d{1,2})){3}$";
        String rebindRegex = "^((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d))|[0-1]?\\d{1,2})(\\.((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d))|[0-1]?\\d{1,2})){3}\\.((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d))|[0-1]?\\d{1,2})(\\.((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d))|[0-1]?\\d{1,2})){3}$";
        if(Pattern.compile(rebindRegex).matcher(subDomain).matches()) {
            String[] s = subDomain.split("\\.");
            byte[] ip = new byte[4];
            byte[] rebindIP = new byte[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (i < 4) {
                    ip[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
                } else {
                    rebindIP[i - 4] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
                }
            }
            if (questionDomainMap.containsKey(dnsQuestion.name())) {
                answerIP = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(questionDomainMap.get(dnsQuestion.name()));
                questionDomainMap.remove(dnsQuestion.name());
            } else {
                answerIP = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(ip);
                questionDomainMap.put(dnsQuestion.name(), rebindIP);
            }
        }else if(Pattern.compile(ipRegex).matcher(subDomain).matches()){
            String[] s = subDomain.split("\\.");
            byte[] ip = new byte[s.length];
            for(int i=0; i < s.length; i++){
                ip[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
            }
            answerIP = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(ip);
        }else{
            answerIP = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] {(byte) 192, (byte) 168, 43, (byte)245});
            System.out.println(dnsQuestion.name());
            System.out.println(1);
        }
        DnsLog dnslog = new DnsLog(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),dnsQuestion.name().substring(0,dnsQuestion.name().length()-1),new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()),connectIP,dnsQuestion.type().toString(),logID);
        dnsLogService.addDnsLog(dnslog);
        response.addRecord(DnsSection.QUESTION, dnsQuestion);
        DefaultDnsRawRecord queryAnswer = new DefaultDnsRawRecord(dnsQuestion.name(), DnsRecordType.A, 0, answerIP);
        response.addRecord(DnsSection.ANSWER, queryAnswer);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
```

This is my result from dig

```
dig aaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa @127.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> aaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57548
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;aaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
aaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa.   0   IN  A   192.168.43.245

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 18 21:24:32 CST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

I tried to use browser connect on `aaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa`, The DNS server return a msg to the browser, but browser connect errors.

When i use nslookup, it gives me this:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
服务器:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.43.245

非权威应答:
名称:    aaaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa
Addresses:  192.168.43.245
          192.168.43.245
```

My code might have an error, but i do not know.

Comment: How do you think your browser will find out your nameserver? It won't/can't, without specific configuration. It just uses the official root and goes down from there. Also at this stage your question is not programming related, hence should be better on [su] or [sf] for example, check their help.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I change browser computer dns to my dns server ip

Comment: What happens if you tell your browser to visit `http://192.168.43.245/` by typing that URL directly into the address bar?

Comment: @ottomeister  visit http://192.168.43.245/ is ok，I visit aaaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa in ie，ie said dns error.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I use another system (debian) change dns to  192.168.43.245 and successful visit aaaa.1.tqtqtq.aaa ,but windows visit domain after change dns fail, i think you are right ,maybe not code error, but i don't know why debian is ok but windows not